# Запятая перед словом пока

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, наречия

Нужна помощь!

Вы даже позвали Арину пока меня не было. Ставится ли запятая? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Смотрите, тут две основы. А в предложениях с двумя основами по кд ставится запятая. Есть конечно исключения со всякими общими обстоятельствами и вводными словами, но тут голые две основы.

Answer (score 1):

Сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) — это вид сложного предложения, в составе которого одно простое предложение по смыслу и интонации подчинено другому.

Зависимое предложение в этом случае называют придаточным, независимое — главным.

Пока - это подчинённый союз времени
А это сложноподчинённое предложение с двумя основами - значит перед "пока" нужна запятая

https://uchipravila.ru/